# How to change the following SQL query to a Linq query

Tags: sql, linq

How to change the following SQL query to Linq query and how to convert results to a list of strings?

```
select Name 
from Categories 
where ID in (select CID from CategoryLink where VID = 57)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What data source do you use in your MVC application? Show us some code!

Answer (score 1):

Please, provide some extra context. From the fist sight the code should be something like this:

```
List<string> names = db.Categories
                       .Where(c => db.CategoryLink.Any(cl=>cl.VID == 57 && CID == c.ID))
                       .ToList();
```